# How to install Anaconda application copied to the C drive

Tags: installation, anaconda

For security reasons my IT team had to put a copy of Anaconda 5.3.0 on my C drive. Apparently, I still need to install it in order to use it. The only executable that looks legitimate is easy_install.exe. When I click on it, a command prompt briefly displays itself and then disappears. Anaconda is not installed. Same happens when I click on anaconda.exe. Is there another executable that I can click on in Anaconda's file directories?